# File-based node js paths

Tags: node.js

Is would it be possible for a node js server to have file-based paths for applications, in the same way as PHP/ASP is normally handled.

```
Request             Page handler
--------------------------------
/                   index.js
/index(.djs)        index.js
/about(.djs)        about.js
/about/me           about.js
```

Would this be possible, and please could example code for an implementation be shown.

Comment: This depends entirely on the framework you use. More details on your app would be helpful.

Comment: @AaronAsAChimp I am very open-ended on frameworks. This is for a new app, with free range on usage.

Comment: You'll probably find this question useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809539/choosing-a-web-application-framework-using-node-js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going out on a limb here that your focus was more on the file based solution. Assuming `/lorem` and `/lorem/ipsum` should be mapped to a handler file called `lorem.js`.

---

So here is yet another example on an [ExpressJS](http://expressjs.com/) solution:

```
npm install express
```

After that create an `app.js` containing the following code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var handlerPath = path.join(path.dirname(__filename), 'handler');
var files = fs.readdirSync(handlerPath);

process.chdir(__dirname);

files.forEach(function (filepath) {
  var handlerName = path.basename(filepath, path.extname(filepath));
  var handler = require(path.join(handlerPath, filepath));
  console.log(handlerName);
  var regEx = new RegExp('^\/' + handlerName + '(\.djs){0,1}(\/.*)*$');
  app.get(regEx, handler);

  if (handlerName === 'index') {
    app.get('/', handler);
  }
});

app.listen(3000);
```

This is assuming you have a directory called `handler` and there should be at least a `index.js` in it.

Each of those files shoud contain a function `module.export = function (req, res) {}` so that it return your specific contents.

i.e. **handler/index.js**:

```
module.exports = function (req, res) {
  res.send('index handler');
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes , this is very simple on using Node.JS Express Framework . Express is a web development framework for node . Rather than linking the routes directly to javascript(.js) files , the routes will be linked to the methods exposed on these javascript files . Here is the [link](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLw2e3dFxewkKLqth2z0xLrsIA0njuW3U7) for the series of video tutorials which will help you understand expressJS and start implementing your objective using the same within no time

Comment: Could I point out that,as the question asks. Please could I have code, et al, for file-based route paths. I am not asking how to build a standard node app.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the very simple implementation using expressJS . 
First do

```
npm install express-3.1.0
```

Here are the 3 files , app.js(the main server file) , about.js and index.js .Place these 3 files in the same folder and run the command

```
node app.js
```

Make sure node is installed in your computer . Here is the code for app.js

```
var express = require('express')
  , index = require('./index.js')//The index.js as you wanting it to be 
  , about = require('./about.js') //again the about.js file 
  , http = require('http');


var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.use(app.router);

});

app.get('/', index.indexPage);//calling indexPage method from index.js for /
app.get('/index',index.indexPage);//calling indexPage method from index.js for /index
app.get('/about', about.list);//calling list method from about.js for /about
app.get('/about/:id',about.thisUser);//calling thisUser method from about.js for /about

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
```

console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});

here is the code for index.js

```
exports.indexPage = function(req, res){ //exposing the indexPAge method 
  res.end('This is the index PAge');
};
```

Here is the code for about.js

```
exports.list = function(req, res){ /*exposing the list method to be able to be called from another file */
  res.end('Enter about the specific user');
};

exports.thisUser = function(req,res){
    res.end("You want to know about the user:" + req.params.id);
};
```

Now go to your browser and visit the routes '127.0.0.1:3000/' , '127.0.0.1:3000/index',127.0.0.1:3000/about',127.0.0.1:3000/about/me' , the operations for these respective routes will be mapped onto the methods in these files

Comment: Nice, but not automated, like the chosen answer.